# How to use LINQ to XML to output &quot; to an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am doing some XML parsing, and I want to be able to have an element that looks like the following:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
   copy &quot;$(BPL_OUTPUT)\$(OUTPUTFILENAME)&quot; &quot;$(QUICKSET_INSTALL)&quot;  
 </PostBuildEvent>
```

I am using the .NET `XDocument` class, calling the `XDocument.Save()` method.

The value of this PostBuildEvent tag is stored in a constant variable, like the following:

```
public const string PostBuildEventScript = 
  "copy &quot;$(BPL_OUTPUT)\\$(OUTPUTFILENAME)&quot; &quot;$(QUICKSET_INSTALL)&quot;";
```

I want to copy the value of this variable to this XML element, but what is printed to the XML document is:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
copy &amp;quot;$(BPL_OUTPUT)\$(OUTPUTFILENAME)&amp;quot; &amp;quot;$(QUICKSET_INSTALL)&amp;quot;
</PostBuildEvent>
```

As you can see, there's an extra amp; that I don't want. I also tried hard coding the variable like:

```
public const string PostBuildEventScript = 
         "copy \"$(BPL_OUTPUT)\\$(OUTPUTFILENAME)\" \"$(QUICKSET_INSTALL)\"";
```

But this resulted in:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
     copy "$(BPL_OUTPUT)\$(OUTPUTFILENAME)" "$(QUICKSET_INSTALL)"
</PostBuildEvent>
```

But as you can see, those are actual double quotes and I wanted "&quot".

How do I handle this problem?

Comment: BTW, it's not "C# LINQ", it's ".NET LINQ", and it's more specifically "LINQ to XML". It's not the "C# XDocument class", it's the ".NET XDocument" class.

Comment: Why do you want to escape " character when it is not necessary to escape it as a text element value?  You only need to escape when it appears in attribute value.

Comment: Tell me if my answer helped you.

Comment: John Saunders: Thanks, good to know. kepler84: I work at a company where &quot; is required instead of actual double quotes as the XElement value. @mybirthname: See my comment on your answer.

Comment: @GabeMeister: you should try to find out why your company requires things that the XML standards do not require.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape `&` and `;`.

```
&#38;quot&#59;
```

You can read it this [Article](http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html) for more escaping of special characters in xml.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The ampersand in the `&#38;` character code is still written to the file as `&amp;`, so now the XElement value looks like: `<PostBuildEvent>copy &amp;#38;quot&amp;#59;$(BPL_OUTPUT)\$(OUTPUTFILENAME)&amp;#38;quot&amp;#59;; &amp;#38;quot&amp;#59;;$(QUICKSET_INSTALL)&amp;#38;quot&amp;#59;;</PostBuildEvent>`.